# Connection error upon returning view from EF controller in ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to return the index view of an EF controller in my ASP.NE MVC project. The error is in Danish, but I will try to translate. "Server not found or there was not access to it. SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50. Error in local database runtime. Cannot create an automatic instance."

This is where the error is located in the code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Udstillingsmodels.ToList());
    }
```

This is the model class:

```
public class Udstillingsmodel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string titel { get; set; }
    public string beskrivelse { get; set; }
    public string billedeSti { get; set; }
}

public class UdstillingsmodelDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Udstillingsmodel> Udstillingsmodels { get; set; }
}
```

This is the added connection string in Web.config:

```
<add name="UdstillingsmodelDBContext" 
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Udstillingsmodels.mdf;Integrated Security=True" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I have added all the references needed for EF to work, so I am unsure what is causing this problem to occur. I'm sorry if I am not providing enough information, I will try to help as best as I can.

Comment: Which version of `LocalDB` do you have installed? Have you tried `v12.0` in your connection string instead of `v11.0`?

Comment: The Dbcontext must have a constructor with default connection String..

Comment: @RajshekarReddy No it doesn't need one, it will default to using the class name of the context.

Comment: @DavidG thank you.. I didn't know that..

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the DbContext which connectionstring to use.
Try adding an empty constructor to your context which passes the connectionstring to the base class:

```
public class UdstillingsmodelDBContext : DbContext
{
    public UdstillingsmodelDBContext() : base("UdstillingsmodelDBContext") {}
    public DbSet<Udstillingsmodel> Udstillingsmodels { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't it use the name of the context if it doesn't get one passed in?

Comment: Having checked to confirm, you do NOT need to so this.

Comment: Good point, you're right David. I guess this is not a solution then :(

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I found the problem. I had an outdated version of localdb installed on my computer.